# Proving limsup of Brownian motion is not zero a.s. using $\mathbb{P}(B_1\leq0,\sup_{t\geq0}B_{t+1}−B_1 =0)$

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, limsup-and-liminf

Consider $M_t:=\sup\limits_{t\geq0}B_t$. I have managed to prove that the law of $M_t$ is concentrated on $\{0,\infty\}$ using the distribution of scaled Brownian motion.

However, I am asked to prove $$\mathbb{P}(M_t=0)\leq\mathbb{P}\left(B_1\leq0,\sup_{t\geq0}B_{t+1}−B_1 =0\right)$$ to show that $\mathbb{P}(M_t=0)=0$, and somehow show that the BM path is not differentiable at zero a.s. Where does the inequality come from? The joint distribution suggests reflection principle, but as with most reflection principle problems I have asked before I am unable to see how to begin; I have seen other questions on this site and they don't seem to use this inequality. Furthermore how does this lead to the subsequent requested results? Thanks!

Comment: What is $Z$? I don't see where you defined it.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy should be $M_t$, sorry copy pasted my LaTeX code wrongly!

Comment: @user107224, Hint: consider $Y_t = B_{t+1} - B_t, t \ge 0$.

It follows from Markov property that $Y_t$ is a Brownian motion, independent of $B_1$. 

Hence $P(B_1 \le 0, sup_t Y_t = 0) = P(B_1 \le 0) P( sup_t Y_t = 0) = P(B_1 \le 0) P( sup_t M_t = 0) = \frac{1}2P( M_t = 0)$.

If $P( M_t = 0) \le  P(B_1 \le 0, sup_t Y_t = 0) $ then $P( M_t = 0) \le  P(B_1 \le 0, sup_t Y_t = 0)  \le  \frac{1}2P( M_t = 0)$ and $P( M_t = 0)  =0$.

Notice also, that if $t=0$ then $M_t = 0$ and $P( M_t = 0) = 1$.

Comment: @BotnakovN. hi thanks! May I ask where the inequality comes from? In particular, it feels like a contradiction with the $t=0$ case.

Comment: @user107224, it's easy to derive that inequality holds true from the fact that both sides are equal to $0$. This fact follows from Markov property and Reflection principle. But it's not what you want.